# Comparing Images with reference images OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, matching

I have been working on a basic gesture control algorithm. I have a set of reference images (commands) and sample images (drawn by the user). I want to compare the sample image with all the reference images and see what command has user tried to enter (assuming they only draw/ try to draw the provided gestures).

However, I am unable to generate a concrete matching algorithm. I have tried matchShapes from OpenCV Library and a correlation function as well. So far, only the correlation function has provided decent results.

Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void cannyThreshold(Mat* src, Mat* detect)
{
    blur(*src, *detect, Size(3, 3));
    Canny(*detect, *detect, 5, 15, 3);
}

double correlation(cv::Mat &image_1, cv::Mat &image_2)
{
    // convert data-type to "float"
    cv::Mat im_float_1;
    image_1.convertTo(im_float_1, CV_32F);
    cv::Mat im_float_2;
    image_2.convertTo(im_float_2, CV_32F);
    int n_pixels = im_float_1.rows * im_float_1.cols;
    // Compute mean and standard deviation of both images
    cv::Scalar im1_Mean, im1_Std, im2_Mean, im2_Std;
    meanStdDev(im_float_1, im1_Mean, im1_Std);
    meanStdDev(im_float_2, im2_Mean, im2_Std);
    assert(im_float_1.size() == im_float_2.size());
    // Compute covariance and correlation coefficient
    double covar = (im_float_1 - im1_Mean).dot(im_float_2 - im2_Mean) / n_pixels;
    //cout << "correl function conversion \n";
    double correl = covar / (im1_Std[0] * im2_Std[0]);
    return correl;
}

int main()
{
    Mat src_a, src_b;
    src_a = imread("../data/ref_sq.png", 0);
    src_b = imread("../data/drawn_sq.png", 0);
    assert( !(src_a.empty() || src_b.empty() ) );
    namedWindow("ref", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("drawn", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    Mat matA, matB;
    Rect boundRectA, boundRectB;
    cannyThreshold(&src_a, &matA);
    cannyThreshold(&src_b, &matB);

    //draw rectangles around the gesture (seperate it from black bkg)
    boundRectA = boundingRect(matA);
    boundRectB = boundingRect(matB);
    rectangle(matA, boundRectA, Scalar(255, 0, 0));
    rectangle(matB, boundRectB, Scalar(255, 0, 0));
    Mat cropA, cropB;

    //resize the gesture images to same size 
    cropA = matA(boundRectA);
    cropB = matB(boundRectB);
    resize(cropA, matA, Size(300, 300));
    resize(cropB, matB, Size(300, 300));
    imshow("ref", matA);
    imshow("drawn", matB);
    double d = correlation(matA, matB);
    float variance = matchShapes(matA, matB, CV_TM_CCORR, 0.0);
    cout << "Variance = " << variance << "\n";
    cout << "Correlation is : " << d << "\n";
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried the combinations of : Square , Triangle and Circle so far.
Here are my results with these combinations 
Variation = 0 for 100% match and Correlation = 1 for 100% match.

```
reference_triangle and drawn_circle 
Variance is : 0.117478   Correlation is : 0.450111
reference_triangle and drawn_triangle
Variance is : 0.146981   Correlation is : 0.506216
reference_triangle and drawn_square
Variance is : 0.133144   Correlation is : 0.449743

reference_square and drawn_circle
Variance is : 0.0244948  Correlation is : 0.478725
reference_square and drawn_triangle
Variance is : 0.00500868 Correlation is : 0.410928
reference_square and drawn_square
Variance is : 0.00882819 Correlation is : 0.512346

reference_circle and drawn_circle
Variance is : 0.0298134  Correlation is : 0.543662
reference_circle and drawn_triangle
Variance is : 0.00030983 Correlation is : 0.402365
reference_circle and drawn_square
Variance is : 0.0141467  Correlation is : 0.473818
```

So now I am wondering, Is there some other way for matching images that I should try? Any help is appreciated.
[image: drawn square by user]

[image: reference square gesture][image]

Comment: have a look at chamfer matching, too.

Comment: @Micka Thank you for responding, I looked into it but I can't figure out how to use it. There is no inbuilt function in OpenCV for this.
There is a matchTemplate function but that won't work as it requires exact image matches.

Comment: you'll have to understand the algorithm, then you can compose it with openCV functions easily. Basically it is: 1. contour extraction or edge detection on both images. 2. distance transform of the template. 3. summing up or averaging or max- the distances of your image. 4. Threshold or choose the best chamfer distance of all templates. But first you'll have to normalize the images to fit size/rotation, maybe with an "iterative closest points" algorithm (icp) or fititing of rotated boinding boxes.